# How to setState depending on post http method response status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I try to set state inside React when I get response from backend (http post method). What I'm going to do is to send data to a server and then, when resp is back, I wanna set `isSubmitting` property as false. that being said, my state doesn't relying on responded data -> only on response status. How can I set state when response is back?

I don't want to just console.log this content, I want to make `this.setState({ isSubmitting })` when content is ready.

I thought about something like:
`if (content) { this.setState({ isSubmitting }) }`

but dunno is that correct.

```
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```

I have resolved problem by replacing async/await for Promises:

```
    return fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(blabla)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(resp => console.log(resp));
```

So now I can setState in last line. But I'm still curious how it works with promises.

Comment: certainly you should use `this.setState` whenever you want to update anything in the component's state. Note that `this.setState({ isSubmitting })` will set the `isSubmitting` property of the state to whatever the value of the variable `isSubmitting` is, so make sure that is defined.

Comment: Yeah I know that setState is the method. But WHEN to put proper code? below `content` declaration? Wouldn't is synchronous and `isSubmitting` will be set before actual data is back?

Comment: yes, there. Did you try it? The whole point of `await` is that it "waits" for the promise to be resolved, allowing you to write asynchronous code as if it were synchronous.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but didn't know is that correct. I read somewhere that that it "waits" only on included parts - in this case, `content` variable. But I didn't want to use `content` to set `isSubmitting` state as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/async-event-handlers-in-react-a1590ed24399) article, You don't even need to create `content` variable and it's just fine to check if response is ok or not (if You use `fetch` it has built-in `ok` property).

```
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
  });
  if (rawResponse.ok) {
    this.setState({ isSubmitting: false }); 
  }
})();
```

Any action/statement which relies on `await` keyword inside `async` function body will wait for it to resolve and then execute.